# How do I configuring cURL so that I can actually use it?

Tags: visual-c++, libcurl, configure

I'm a beginner I am using using Microsoft Visual C++. I need a step by step walkthrough from downloading up till actually using libcurl if anyone can help? I don't know much terminology though.
Everyone seems to skip all that and goes straight into putting #include  in their files but I don't know how to get to that step.

I know I have to tell Visual C++ that I'm using another library but how do I do that? How do I configure this library and include the directories?

Any help is very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they have a .pdf explaining step by step how to build a project with libcurl, here is the link

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/visual_studio.pdf

hope that helps

Comment: I follow what it says, open it up the  .dsw file "vc6curl.dsw" in visual and click build but it comes up with this error over a hundred times in the output window: 
"curl-7.22.0\lib\setup.h(225) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory "

Comment: hmm, thats odd. what version of windows are you using? also what version of Visual Studio are you currently running?

Comment: using windows XP and visualC++is 2005- do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: yeah, i think using Visual Studio 2005 could be the problem, the libcurl project was compiled with Visual Studio 6, try installing VC6 and then recompiling, i also had success using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Is there any difference between Visual C++ 2010 Express and Visual Studio 2010? and thanks for the help so far!

Comment: well, Visual Studio is just a suite, usually comes with Visual Basic, C#, Visual C++, etc. so no, not really. and your welcome =]

Comment: awesome I'll give it a go and come back if there's any problems